# Query to find duplicate record in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have query to find duplicate records :

```
select min(a.rowindex)rowindx, b.rowindex rowindx1 
from dedupinitial1 a,
dedupinitial1 b 
where a.rowindex < b.rowindex 
 and a.name = b.name
group by b.rowindex
order by 1;
```

But this gives me result like :

```
3   182161
3   121963
3   41619
3   219762
3   163808
3   122614
3   271
3   163809
3   81
4   75060
4   60086
4   109294
4   98135
4   98468
4   165069
```

But I want result like

```
3   182161
    3   121963
    3   41619
    3   219762
    3   163808
    3   122614
    3   271
    3   163809
    3   81
    3    3
    4   75060
    4   60086
    4   109294
    4   98135
    4   98468
    4   165069
    4    4
```

My desire result also include 3 and 4 in group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
select min(a.rowindex)rowindx, b.rowindex rowindx1 
from dedupinitial1 a,
dedupinitial1 b 
where a.rowindex <= b.rowindex 
 and a.name = b.name
group by b.rowindex
order by 1;
```

Comment: not when you are staring at the query for a long time, simple solutions just skips our minds for some reason :D